# opencv mean function for gray image implemention via neon

Tags: c++, opencv, neon

```
uint64_t sum = 0;
const uint8_t* src = (const uint8_t*)gray.data;
int i, k, w = gray.cols, h = gray.rows, pitch = gray.step.p[0], w32 = w >> 5 << 5;

for(i = 0; i < h; ++ i)
{
    const uint8_t* line = src;
    for(k = 0; k < w32; k += 32)
    {
        uint8x16_t a16 = vld1q_u8(line);    line += 16;
        uint8x16_t b16 = vld1q_u8(line); line += 16;

        uint16x8_t a8 = vpaddlq_u8(a16);
        uint16x8_t b8 = vpaddlq_u8(b16);

        uint32x4_t a4 = vpaddlq_u16(a8);
        uint32x4_t b4 = vpaddlq_u16(b8);

        uint64x2_t a2 = vpaddlq_u32(a4);
        a2 = vpadalq_u32(a2, b4);

        sum += vgetq_lane_u64(a2, 0) + vgetq_lane_u64(a2, 1);
    }

    for( ; k < w; ++ k)
        sum += src[k];

    src += pitch;
}

printf("%f\t%f", (double)sum / (double)(w * h), cv::mean(gray));
```

When I tested by a binary image, the result is equal.
When the image is grayscal, the result not equal, but I can't find the problem in my code.

Edit: now, upper code is right, the benchmark of loop 1000 times for a 8bit gray image is:

cv::mean 0.000328
myMean   0.000091

Comment: Why do `line += 16` twice rather than `line += 32`?

Comment: What has this got to do with OpenCV? What is `w32` set to? What is that double shifted formula for `wBy32` actuallly doing? Have you tested on a solid black image, a solid white image and a mid-grey image?

Comment: It is do sum for all pixels, then divide by area. I found the problem: "uint8x16_t a16 = vld1q_u8(src); line += 16;", the "src" need change to "line", a stupid mistake

Comment: thanks for every one:) now upper code is worked

Comment: I don't see the point. A non-neon version would be at least five times as fast using the instruction `usada8` on `ARMv7`, or even `ARMv6` a.k.a. `ARM11`.

Comment: Most probably the performance comparison of yours is to a plain C version. You should ask yourself what you did wrong since the neon version of yours isn't approximately 32 times as fast in this case: Do not access the same memory area with both ARM and NEON; Don't do anything unnecessary inside the loop, such as computing the 64bit sum; Never ever move values from NEON registers to ARM ones inside a loop. Do these, the performance will more than ten fold.

Comment: Yes, I had optimized this code, thank you very much:)